# how to Reffere two schemas in mongoose in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

solve my ignorence... I'm not able to understand how mongoose is acting with reference "**Population**" maybe... for example if **school** is one schema and **students** is other ...and if a student reffer to school schema how??...
**school schema:**

```js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    organizationName:   { type: String },
    Location:   { type: String },
    students: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'students' }]
}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('school', schoolSchema);

console.log("school schema defined")
```

**students schema:**

```js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var studentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:   { type: String },
    class:  { type: String },

}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('students', studentsSchema);

console.log("students schema defined")
```

if i have separate **services**

*school middleware:*

```js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var schoolModel = require('../model/schoolSchema');

 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      schoolModel.find(function (err, data) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(data);
    });
  },
 router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
     schoolModel.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  }
module.exports = router
```

similarly *students middleware*

and in **angular controller** i dont know how to call with refference obj!!! but i made somthing

```js
'use strict';

    var app =angular.module('school');
        app.controller('controller', ['$scope', '$cookieStore','$http', controller]);

    function controller($scope, $cookieStore, $http) {
//getting all data
    var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('/schoolApi').success(function(response) {
          $scope.dataSchool = response;
          $scope.school = "";
          });
      };
    refresh();
//add data
    $scope.add = function(){
        var inData       = $scope.school;
        inData.students = $scope.students;
        console.log(inData);
        $http.post('/schoolApi',inData).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            refresh();
        });
    };
```

*thanks in advance*